# Runing Django tests with Jenkinsfile (with docker)

Tags: django, jenkins

i have a Django app running inside Docker (also Postgres, Nginx and Jenkins are inside docker),
and i want to run tests by creating a Pipeline

The problem is that every time i run it with **python app/manage.py** test (since the jenkisnfile is outside the project folder named "app") ,it just run an empty test.py file (so it return 0 test succesfull) even though i have actual tests.

if i ran the test directly from the terminal it work

```
$ docker-compose run web python manage.py test
Creating proj1_web_run ... done
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
..........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.229s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'..
```

here is Jenkinsfile

```
      pipeline {
        agent {
            docker { image 'python:3.9' }
        }
        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps {
                    sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
                }
            }

            stage('Test') {
                steps {
                    sh 'python app/manage.py test'
                }
            }

            stage('Deploy') {
                steps {
                    sh 'echo not yet...'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

message in Jenkins console output

```
+ python app/manage.py test
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing to do with jenkins or docker. The Django test runner searches the current directory (and subdirectories if it's a python package).  You can either `cd app` first, or specify the directory:

`python app/manage.py test ./app`